# sqldf doesn't install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, sqldf

I'm trying to install sqldf package in an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘sqldf’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

I tried to install the library [libpq-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libpq-dev/download) as suggested from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849008/unable-to-install-sqldf-on-linux) post, but I still receive the message.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to update R, but I'm getting the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.1.2-1precise0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.1.2-1precise0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried the solutions [in this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218708/installing-latest-version-of-r-base), but none worked

Comment: Ubuntu 14 isn't a thing.  You should specify 14.04 or 14.10

Comment: I followed [these instructions][1] and everything worked!
 

  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/496788/you-have-held-broken-package-while-trying-to-install-r

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the [package page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html):

```
Depends:    R (≥ 3.1.0), gsubfn (≥ 0.6), proto, RSQLite (≥ 1.0.0)
```

As the error message clearly states, you are using an older R 3.0.2 which is less than the required 3.1.0.

The fix is easy: read the [Ubuntu-specific README](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), make the adjustment to install (current !!) R binaries as .deb package via `apt-get` from CRAN -- and you will have R 3.1.2 in no time.

Which will permit you to install the current sqldf as well.

Comment: It is all in the README I pointed you to. Update the info for apt, run `apt-get update`, and the next `apt-get dist-upgrade` will get you new R.  You can also use the GUIs and what not -- thousands of us use these packages this way.

Answer (score 3):

I followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496788/you-have-held-broken-package-while-trying-to-install-r) and everything worked!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Comment: Please delete this. It is not an answer, but at best a comment or maybe worth an edit of your question (but not *both* as well as an answer). It is also exactly what is in the README I pointed you to.

Comment: if you can't complete the bing project let me know, it's getting urgent for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this resolved with this try this out:

```
# Install function for packages    
packages<-function(x) {    
  x<-as.character(match.call()[[2]])
  if (!require(x,character.only=TRUE)) {
    install.packages(pkgs=x,repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
    require(x,character.only=TRUE)
  }
}

packages(ggplot2)
packages(reshape2)
packages(plyr)
# etc ...other packages
```

that's all enjoy..!!